# Cannot resolve MapActivity class on Android

Tags: android

I have an application which has 11 different activities.  One of these activities is an extension of MapActivity (it is a map for data visualization).  To get to this activity the user must first travel through the launch activity, then 3 other activities.  The code to launch the MapActivity is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapVis.class);
i.putExtra("edu.uml.cs.isense.visualizations.session_list", sessions);
startActivity(i);
```

When this is executed I get the following output from the Log:

```
09-01 14:36:22.389: WARN/dalvikvm(592): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Ledu/uml/cs/isense/visualizations/MapVis;(0x44981910):0x128260 ref [Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity;] Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity;(0x44981910):0x13d330
09-01 14:36:22.389: WARN/dalvikvm(592): (Ledu/uml/cs/isense/visualizations/MapVis; had used a different Lcom/google/android/maps/MapActivity; during pre-verification)
09-01 14:36:22.389: WARN/dalvikvm(592): Unable to resolve superclass of Ledu/uml/cs/isense/visualizations/MapVis; (118)
09-01 14:36:22.389: WARN/dalvikvm(592): Link of class 'Ledu/uml/cs/isense/visualizations/MapVis;' failed
09-01 14:36:22.389: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(592): Shutting down VM
09-01 14:36:22.389: WARN/dalvikvm(592): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7f0)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu.uml.cs.isense.visualizations.MapVis
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at edu.uml.cs.isense.visualizations.Visualizations.onOptionsItemSelected(Visualizations.java:213)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2195)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:209)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
09-01 14:36:22.399: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(592):     ... 17 more
09-01 14:36:22.409: WARN/ActivityManager(92):   Force finishing activity edu.uml.cs.isense/.visualizations.Visualizations
09-01 14:36:22.909: WARN/ActivityManager(92): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44c84a90 edu.uml.cs.isense/.visualizations.Visualizations}
```

I do have the target set to Google APIs, this is an app meant for Android 1.5, and specifies the minsdk to be level 3 in the manifest file.  uses-library for maps is also in manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="edu.uml.cs.isense"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Isense" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <activity android:name=".experiments.Experiments" android:label="@string/app_name_experiments"/>
  <activity android:name=".sessions.Sessions" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  <activity android:name=".people.People" android:label="@string/app_name_people"/>
  <activity android:name=".profile.Profile" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  <activity android:name=".sensors.Sensors" android:label="@string/app_name_sensors"/>
  <activity android:name=".visualizations.DataTable" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  <activity android:name=".visualizations.Visualizations" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  <activity android:name=".sensors.DataListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/selectFile"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".sensors.Upload" android:label="@string/app_name_uploader"/>
        <activity android:name=".visualizations.MapVis" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
</manifest>
```

I have been at this for almost 2 days now with no results.  It seems that there are a lot of people having issues launching a MapActivity from other activities but there are no solutions anywhere.  Does anyone have a clue?  Thanks.

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7644635/779408

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently at some point my build environment got really messed up.  It looked like I somehow had the google APIs jar in my project twice, causing a conflict.  I deleted the project and recreated it, works now.

Comment: Do you know that if you know accept your own answer you get the “Self learner” badge? You already got the needed three up votes.

Comment: Same thing. I manually added google maps to the build path again after eclipse prompted me to. After recreating a few times and it not working, I followed @cyber-monk instructions and removed the maps jar from the build. worked great after.

Answer (score 65):

The problem is that your **MapVis** class is likely extending **com.google.android.maps.MapActivity**.  For the system to be able to find this class you need to do two things:

First make sure your project is including the Android **maps.jar** in your build path.  From Eclipse find

```
Project > Properties > Android
```

Then select one of the "Google APIs" as appropriate for you app. You can confirm that maps.jar is on your build path by checking:

```
Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Expand "Google Apis"
```

Second browse to your manifest file and make sure you have the `uses-library` snippet nested within the `<application>` tags as follows:

```
<manifest>
...
   <application ...>
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
      ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

May the force be with you!

Comment: apparently under `Project > Properties > Android` selecting `google api` means you are also selecting the android library! Grr!

Comment: "" make sure you have the uses-library snippet nested within the <application> tags  "" a real life saver, thank you!

Comment: You saved my life! I didn't added `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in my manifest :)

Answer (score 13):

I had this exact same problem.

I was adding the maps.jar manually in the build path and using android 2.1 as the target. This does not seem to work (not on 2.1 anyway) despite the tutorial i followed saying to do it like this.

How i solved it was:

**-Remove the manually added maps.jar then i set my build target to Google APIs 2.1 instead of Android 2.1**

I realised afterwards that the maps.jar is automatically included in the "Google" Android libs so was conflicting. :D

Comment: perfect that was my problem :)

Answer (score 5):

I update cyber-monk answer because the problem is not that you do not have maps.jar, the problem is that you have conflicting jar (e.g you mix maps.jar with android 4.0).
So

1. ensure that **Google APIs** is checked in `Project > Properties > Android`. If that not the case select it and click on apply. This change will modify the target property in the file **project.properties** and change the **included libraries**. (e.g with the latest android sdk, you will have: `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:14`)
2. go to `Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries` and ensure that there is no **android.jar** or **maps.jar** directly included. You should only have **Google Apis** with at least **maps.jar** and **android.jar** as leaves.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using Android studio and gradle:

1. Completely remove maps.jar (and any other libs added for google maps) from dependencies.
2. In your projects manifest and in your maps-library (if you are using one) module add this line in 'application' section:

   < uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
3. In your projects build.gradle file (and also in maps library gradle if you are using one) modify compileSdkVersion:

   compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
4. Clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I realized you cannot just add the map library to the project, you have to change the target to something like this `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8` instead of `android=android-8`.

Anyway thanks you gave me the hint to discover it ;)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

on your Android  .jar right click Build Path-> Configure Build Path. then if you see 2 maps.jar includes remove one of them...

Comment: So true, this happened to me also when I added Google Maps support to an existing project. If you first add the code and accept when Eclipse tells you to include maps.jar, and then change the build target, you end up with 2 maps.jar in your build-path.

Answer (score 2):

John's answer worked for me.  It took me forever to come across this solution.  A great page for working with the MapActivity is [here](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/01/18/using-google-maps-in-your-android-app/).  It covers most of the problems encountered when working with it, including the solution John had.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and tried all the above proposed solutions (except rebuilding the project) with no success.  Then I cleaned the project and it was fixed.  In Eclipse Project>Clean check your project and select ok.

Comment: had the same problem and a simple project clean did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in my case it turned out that the maps.jar was also sitting in my libs directory. Removing it from that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@cyber-monk's (sorry, can't comment on answers yet) answer is similar to every other answer on the internet, except that it shows one very important detail that most leave out. You have to put the  tag within the  tag. Most just say to put it in the manifest without saying WHERE to put it. I put it inside  and finally, FINALLY got it to work

Answer (score 0):

One other most probable reason as it turned out was the fact that there were conflicting libs ,so resulting into those ClassLoading issues,it is good to remove the other unneccessary libs. If you have included the google maps Lib as suggested by previous contributors then do remove them,so that your project now looks like the following below.

[image]

[image]

Another Possible Cause is the package declaration on your manifest .
[image]