# ClassNotFoundException in Android

Tags: android

Hy!

I get a ClassNotFoundException but don't know why.

Code:

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Main.this,MView.class),1);



package android.korn.geopictureview;

import com.google.android.maps.*;

public class MView extends MapActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
    <activity android:name=".Main" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MView"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Log:

```
   05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.korn.geopictureview.MView
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.korn.geopictureview.Main.onActivityResult(Main.java:49)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3828)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3325)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3371)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1893)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:209)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-28 16:00:28.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1925):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen when you have more then one reference to the maps.jar in your project, double check that it is added and referenced only once.

Comment: Then check you are building against Google API. If nothing works, try cleaning your project, because there must be something messed up in your references: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621163/cannot-resolve-mapactivity-class-on-android.