# Problem in launching Google MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-intent

I am trying to launch a `MapActivity` from `Activity` using intent.

Following is how i defined my `MapActivity`

```
public class googlemap extends MapActivity 
{
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       ... //logic code
    }
}
```

I am trying to launch this `MapActivity` from `Activty` using following `Intent`:

```
//Viewreport is the Activity name
intent = new Intent(Viewreport.this,googlemap.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

It gives me following error in logcat:

```
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pam.com.pampkg.googlemap
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at pam.com.pampkg.Viewreport$btnmaplist.onClick(Viewreport.java:61)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-23 15:48:22.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also, I have added following to the `Manifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".googlemap" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Could someone tell what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: which is your first activity load when you start your application ? Please post your manifest file..

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding the project? Seems like a compiler bug, rather then a mistake in the code.

Comment: Did you tried it without the intent filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just re installed the android sdk and it worked fine. Thanks everyone for help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Add uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
   in the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at this: [Cannot resolve MapActivity class on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621163/cannot-resolve-mapactivity-class-on-android)?