# Application falling when trying to invoke activity via scheme mechanism

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to add handler for custom scheme... i've registered scheme in my application manifest, but all fails to start.

My manifest file part:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SmsMarketApplication">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
        <activity android:name="com.a1systems.smsmarket.ViewMapActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="standard" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="freesmsmap" android:host="localhost" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
...
</application>
```

code part with which i'm trying to invoke viewer:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent dataViewerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  
                contentLink);  

        owner.startActivity(dataViewerIntent);  
    }
```

ContentLink looks like this:

```
freesmsmap://localhost?long=37,68888012&lat=55,76819212
```

But instead of starting activity i got this error:

```
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
09-20 18:24:20.887: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9580):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am i doing wrong? It seems like it could not find needed class... Or uses wrong version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a google Maps API problem. I would check to make sure you are building with the Google APIs.

also check this out. [Cannot resolve MapActivity class on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621163/cannot-resolve-mapactivity-class-on-android)

Comment: yes, I added maps.jar manually instead of setting build target "Android with google API" - thanx