# How to move Activity to mapActivity in android application

Tags: android

I have one application. I need to display map view when we click on button. Actually this button is in one class and google map is in another class. Now when i click on that button , In android Emulator it displays message android application stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: posting some code would be helpful. But why cant you just launch the second activity (map activity) when you click on the button in the 1st activity? Should be fairly easy.

Comment: Posting the exception stack shown in Logcat would also be helpful. Might be ClassNotFoundException or something we can hardly think of.

Comment: 09-28 14:51:27.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.popcornapps.moviecorn.Example
Example is my present activity when i extending this activity to MapActivtiy its show error in Intent i = new intent(Example.this,Map.class) Line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Like @Nipuna Silva said , add a
   `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`
   in your AndroidManfiest.xml. Inside the `<application>` node.
2. Try `Project->clean` in your Eclipse to rebuild your project.
3. Answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621163/cannot-resolve-mapactivity-class-on-android/3621387#3621387) May help you.

Answer (score 0):

Posting some code will help. Make sure you have extended the second activity as MapActivity. Also, the emulator must be google-maps emulator and not the normal ones. Depending on your SDK, create the new AVD and choose GoogleMaps API. I think that should solve the problem

Comment: i am extending one activity to mapActivity,i am using google maps emulator but still i am getting application stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: Have you added both the activities in the AndroidManifest xml file? if you tend to miss adding the activities in manifest, it will throw this error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put

```
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in your AndroidManfiest file

Answer (score 0):

These examples may help you to understand why you are getting the error msg ,and both are doing same (call one map activity class from another...)

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mappingDemo.html

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html

Donot forget to add your map activity in the manifest.xml :

Comment: In my application i have many Actitvitys when i extending one activity to other activity its going forward,But when i extenting activity to MapActivity its showing error in

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(present.this,map.class);

Comment: For the above intent try using Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),map.class);
startActivity(i);