# Android NoClassDefFoundError when create intent

Tags: android, android-mapview, noclassdeffounderror

I got a NoClassDefFoundError when try to create an intent for a class which inherited from MapActivity.

here is the code where I got the exception: Intent mapTabIntent = new Intent(this, MapTab.class); Where this is the TabActivity

I tired with Android version 2.1 and 2.2 Google APIs.
I put the manifest file outside the application:

I used in manifest the android.permission.INTERNET too.

My application is works perfectly without the MapTab.
I already recreate the MapTab class and maptab layout, the result is same.

What I missed out?

Comment: add maps.jar to the class path var in eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android
try this link , it might help you

Answer (score 0):

check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719847/1317080
It seems your problem has to do with the vm not finding the google maps class you inherited from

Comment: The maps.jar file is in Google APIs, project properties Java build path libraries

Comment: can you post the complete logcat output?

Comment: I put the <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> outside of application in the manifest file.
If I put it between <application> ... </application> I got another error: requires unavailable feature android.hardware.sensor.light; failing! and my app didn1t started.
I use light sensor and I defined the usage it.
<uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.sensor.light"/>

Comment: i just tried it myself with api level 10 including google apis. I subclassed from MapActivity. Added <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> INSIDE the application tag and declared the activity <activity android:name=".MapKar"></activity> also INSIDE the application tag. The hardware feature is unrelated.

Comment: LogCat:
E/dalvikvm(248): Could not find class 'com.ekl.mobile.apps.gtl.MapTab', referenced from method com.ekl.mobile.apps.gtl.Main.onCreate
E/AndroidRuntime(248): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(248): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ekl.mobile.apps.gtl.MapTab
E/AndroidRuntime(248):  at com.ekl.mobile.apps.gtl.Main.onCreate(Main.java:1249)
1249. line: Intent mapTabIntent = new Intent(this, MapTab.class);

Comment: that is exactly the error you'd get when the line <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> is missing in your application tag in your manifest file

Comment: I put it into application tags and I got another error.
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
E/PackageManager(52): Package com.ekl.mobile.apps.gtl requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!

Comment: The previous error fixed automatically and I got again the feature error:
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE
com.ekl.mobile.apps.gtl requires unavailable feature android.hardware.location; failing!
BUT if I remove all MapView related lines from manifest/uses-library/ and the tab creation for MapView, it forks perfectly.
It's strange...

Comment: do you test on an emulator or a device without a gps chip? try setting this in your manifest <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>

Comment: I got a same error with set to false on emulator on device I not tried.
I tested without MapView on device and emulator it works perfectly.
With MapView not works at all.