# My simple test case does not run on Robotium

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robotium, android-testing

I am trying to test my application with Robotium using an extremely simple test case but it fails. I have tried everything and nothing works. My main activity is a Google Maps Activity. I've tried other activities but they don't work as well. My package name is correct.

This I have tried:

- Importing Robotium
- Checking Robotium in Order and Export
- Restart Eclipse and Clean Project
- Set debuggable to true in the manifest file.

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.neatspots.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RUN_INSTRUMENTATION" />
    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.app.neatspots" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my simple test class:

```
package android.test;

import com.app.neatspots.MainActivity;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class MainActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
        this.solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void testClick()
    {
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Check on first activity", MainActivity.class);
    }
}
```

Here is my LogCat. I put it in pastebin as well because it's ugly here. http://pastebin.com/GuvcRuHg

```
04-05 20:54:33.402: W/dalvikvm(19668): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/app/neatspots/MainActivity;(0x414e7fe0):0x2068c8 ref [Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap$OnMapLongClickListener;] Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap$OnMapLongClickListener;(0x414e7fe0):0x23ac70
04-05 20:54:33.402: W/dalvikvm(19668): (Lcom/app/neatspots/MainActivity; had used a different Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap$OnMapLongClickListener; during pre-verification)
04-05 20:54:33.402: I/dalvikvm(19668): Failed resolving Lcom/app/neatspots/MainActivity; interface 818 'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap$OnMapLongClickListener;'
04-05 20:54:33.402: W/dalvikvm(19668): Link of class 'Lcom/app/neatspots/MainActivity;' failed
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668): Cannot load class. Make sure it is in your apk. Class name: 'com.app.neatspots.MainActivity'. Message: com.app.neatspots.MainActivity
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.neatspots.MainActivity
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.createPackageInfo(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:88)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.access$000(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:39)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource$1.load(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:50)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource$1.load(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:47)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.SimpleCache.get(SimpleCache.java:31)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.getPackageInfo(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:72)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.getSubpackages(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:48)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.addTopLevelClassesTo(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:61)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.getTopLevelClassesRecursive(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:55)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.testCaseClassesInPackage(TestGrouping.java:156)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.addPackagesRecursive(TestGrouping.java:117)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.includePackages(TestSuiteBuilder.java:102)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:358)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3932)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/neatspots/MainActivity
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    ... 26 more
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:195)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:315)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:58)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-05 20:54:33.407: W/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(19668):    ... 26 more
04-05 20:54:33.442: D/dalvikvm(19668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 498K, 7% free 9028K/9607K, paused 2ms+2ms
04-05 20:54:33.492: D/dalvikvm(1988): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1602K, 35% free 25226K/38279K, paused 3ms+8ms
04-05 20:54:33.502: E/DataRouter(1828): usb connection is true 
04-05 20:54:33.502: E/DataRouter(1828): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
04-05 20:54:33.502: D/dalvikvm(19668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 487K, 6% free 9052K/9607K, paused 1ms+2ms
04-05 20:54:33.592: D/dalvikvm(19668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 537K, 6% free 9146K/9671K, paused 2ms+8ms
04-05 20:54:33.662: D/dalvikvm(19668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 614K, 7% free 9066K/9735K, paused 2ms+2ms
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988): *** mReceiver: VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988):    stream: 3
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988):    volume: 15
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988): *** mReceiver: VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988):    stream: 9
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988):    volume: 15
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988): *** mReceiver: VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988):    stream: 10
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FMRadioService(1988):    volume: 0
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FmRadioController(1988): Jni player_SetVolume :0 
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FmRadioController(1988): ---Jni player_SetVolume---
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FmRadioController(1988): Jni player_muteOn
04-05 20:54:33.692: I/FmRadioController(1988): Jni player_muteOn
04-05 20:54:33.722: D/dalvikvm(19668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 493K, 7% free 9085K/9735K, paused 1ms+2ms
04-05 20:54:33.787: D/dalvikvm(19668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 530K, 7% free 9066K/9735K, paused 1ms+2ms
04-05 20:54:33.842: D/dalvikvm(19668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 510K, 7% free 9068K/9735K, paused 1ms+2ms
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668): Failed to create test.
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:262)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:371)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3932)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:94)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  at android.test.ListLocationsTest.<init>(ListLocationsTest.java:14)
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestSuiteBuilder(19668):  ... 18 more
04-05 20:54:33.852: I/TestRunner(19668): started: testSuiteConstructionFailed(android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests)
04-05 20:54:33.872: I/TestRunner(19668): finished: testSuiteConstructionFailed(android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests)
04-05 20:54:33.872: I/TestRunner(19668): passed: testSuiteConstructionFailed(android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests)
04-05 20:54:33.887: D/AndroidRuntime(19644): Shutting down VM
04-05 20:54:33.887: I/ActivityManager(1988): Force stopping package com.app.neatspots uid=10139
04-05 20:54:33.887: I/ActivityManager(1988): Killing proc 19668:com.app.neatspots/10139: force stop
```

Comment: look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621163/cannot-resolve-mapactivity-class-on-android#answer-5719847

Comment: Btw it's not a problem, if you have only one test method, however you should instantiate solo in setUp method. Also you have missed tearDown.

Comment: I was watching the Robotium video tutorial provided by the official website and that's what they do :S

Comment: Also, my Android application is running perfectly fine. It's on the market...

Comment: I'm sure, you are doing it wrong. This video is obsolete.
http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: I've instantiated solo in setUp and added the teardown method but it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you upload your application somewhere else? It's not available for every country

Comment: Umm, I don't know where else I can upload it that doesn't require me to pay again. What country are you in?

Comment: I've set it to be distributable in Poland. It'll take a few hours for changes to take effect. Nevertheless, I've already tested my application with various users around the UK and USA who have different devices and Android versions and they all work fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27670/discussion-between-maszter-and-johnathan-au)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloaded your application. Here is the test I've prepared for this file. Anyway I don't have sources, so it must be a bit different:

```
package com.app.neatspots.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity> {

    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME = "com.app.neatspots.MainActivity";
    private static Class<?> launchActivityClass;
    static {
        try {
            launchActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    private Solo solo;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Test() {
        super((Class<Activity>) launchActivityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testRecorded() throws Exception {
        solo.waitForActivity("MainActivity");
        solo.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

It works for me:
[image]
Attached project as well:
http://www.speedyshare.com/hf3hP/MyApkTest.zip

Comment: I don't know, what your problem is related to. I gave you only hints with constructor and setUp, as I cannot see your environment, project...

Comment: I think it was ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity> in the class signature as I put MainActivity as opposed to Activity

Comment: Don't think so, if MainActivity extends Activity, it's correct as well

Comment: You didn't get it. His test didn't even run. My finished without problems. It doesn't matter what is inside test method at all in this case...